# I need your help on creating indicator functions

Tags: r, quantmod

Thanks for helping me.
I want to create functions of indicators. It work on TTR::SMA but not for TRR::ATR or TTR::Donchian Channel

Here is the example of what's work. (SMA)

```
# Create SMA function
n = 10
sma <- function(x, return_format = "tibble", n = n) {
  # Convert tibble to xts
  if (!is.xts(x)) {
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by = x$Date)
  }
  # Get SMA 
  sma_xts <- SMA(x = x$Adjusted, n = n) # I want sma on Adjusted Price
  # Rename
  names(sma_xts) <- "SMA"
  # Return in xts format if tibble is not specified
  if (return_format == "tibble") {
    sma <- fortify.zoo(sma_xts, names = "Date")
  } else {
    sma <- sma_xts
  }
  sma
}
```

However, when I want to apply this with ATR or DonchianChannel, it showned NA.

```
# Create DonchianChannel
n = 10
dc <- function(x, return_format = "tibble", n = n) {
  # Convert tibble to xts
  if (!is.xts(x)) {
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by = x$Date)
  }
  # Get DonchianChannel
  dc_xts <- DonchianChannel(x = c(x$High,x$Low), n = n) # <<< I think here is the problem
  # Rename
  names(dc_xts) <- "DC"
  # Return in xts format if tibble is not specified
  if (return_format == "tibble") {
    
    dc <- fortify.zoo(dc_xts, names = "Date")
    
  } else {
    dc <- dc_xts
  }
  dc
}
```

My best guess is the input of function was wrong. Because SMA need x but DonchianChannel need HL. So I have tried many format but I still didn't get it.

```
SMA(x, n = 10, ...)
ATR(HLC, n = 14, maType, ...)
DonchianChannel(HL, n = 10, include.lag = FALSE)
```

Thank you guys for enlightening me :) I'm trying to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering a few issues. The first is defining n outside the function. The promise of n will give an issue inside the `DonchianChannel` call. The second is that the `DonchianChannel` function doesn't expect an object **x**, but an object **HL**.
The third issue is that the function returns 3 columns, not 1, so your rename will fail.

I created a working example without renaming anything.

```
library(quantmod)
aapl <- getSymbols("AAPL", from = Sys.Date() - 366, to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)

# set default values in the function definition, like n = 10
dc <- function(x, return_format = "tibble", n = 10) {
  # Convert tibble to xts
  if (!is.xts(x)) {
    x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by = x$Date)
  }
  # Get DonchianChannel, note that donchian needs HL, not x
  dc_xts <- TTR::DonchianChannel(HL = cbind(x$High, x$Low), n = n) 

  # Return in xts format if tibble is not specified
  if (return_format == "tibble") {
    dc <- fortify.zoo(dc_xts, names = "Date")
  } else {
    dc <- dc_xts
  }
  dc
}

head(dc(aapl), 15)
         Date   high     mid    low
1  2021-09-20     NA      NA     NA
2  2021-09-21     NA      NA     NA
3  2021-09-22     NA      NA     NA
4  2021-09-23     NA      NA     NA
5  2021-09-24     NA      NA     NA
6  2021-09-27     NA      NA     NA
7  2021-09-28     NA      NA     NA
8  2021-09-29     NA      NA     NA
9  2021-09-30     NA      NA     NA
10 2021-10-01 147.47 143.290 139.11
11 2021-10-04 147.47 142.870 138.27
12 2021-10-05 147.47 142.870 138.27
13 2021-10-06 147.47 142.870 138.27
14 2021-10-07 147.47 142.870 138.27
15 2021-10-08 145.96 142.115 138.27
```

The `ATR` function needs a HLC object and in that order. If you make a function do use this function make sure any `cbind` is in the correct order. Always check the returns of the functions, because a lot of financial functions return more that one column.

Comment: Your explaination are very clear. It is very helpful. I got to understand why it doesn't work. Thank you a lot! Cheer!.

Comment: You can use quantmod's extractor functions to get the columns and in the correct order (e.g. `HLC()`, `HL()`, etc)... and ugh, I just noticed that I implemented `HL()` but didn't export it. That will be in the next release.